# How do I install Python/Django Modules?

Tags: python, django

I know absolutely nothing about Django, but I am needing to get an existing project running in OSX.

From the project's directory I run `python manage.py runserver` and get the error: `Error: No module named cms`.

Seems like the INSTALLED_APPS constant (in settings.py)  defines the required modules... but how do I install the dang things?

Is there a standard way of installing dependencies in bulk (like Ruby's Bundler)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you can install all dependencies in once, if there is a requirements.txt file! you just have to run the follow command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

otherwise you can install one by one:

```
pip install django-cms
```

Here is the PIP documentation:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

if you are used to ruby, you can compared to ruby GEM

Answer (score 9):

The entries in [`INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS) are package designations. [Packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) are a way of structuring Python’s module namespace.

> When importing a package, Python searches through the directories on `sys.path` looking for the package subdirectory.

So python has some designated places to look for packages.

To install packages by name to the right location on your system, you could download some python source code and run the `setup.py` script (usually provided by libraries and applications).

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pytz/pytz-2011n.tar.bz2
$ tar xvfj pytz-2011n.tar.bz2
$ cd pytz-2011n
$ python setup.py install
```

There are, however, shortcuts to this, namely [easy_install](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall) and it's successor [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html). With these tools, installation of a third-party package (or django app) boils down to:

```
$ pip install pytz
```

Or, if you use the systems default Python installation:

```
$ sudo pip install pytz
```

That's it. You can now use this library, whereever you want. To check, if it installed correctly, just try it in the console:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Aug 20 2011, 05:03:24)
...
>>> import pytz # you would get an ImportError, if pytz could not be found
>>> pytz.__version__ 
'2011n'
```

Now for the sake of brevity (this post is much to long already), let's assume pytz were some third party django application. You would just write:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'pytz',
)
```

And pytz would be available in your project.

Note: I you have the time, please take a look at [Tools of the Modern Python Hacker: Virtualenv, Fabric and Pip](http://www.clemesha.org/blog/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip/) blog post, which highlights some great python infrastructure tools.