# What does install django-app as a user library means?

Tags: python, django

I just finished my first Django-app and I now have a .tar.gz file. (It's my first one ever: :'))

After having the .tar.gz file I was like ok... now what's next? How do I install this? I found this question: [How do I install Python/Django Modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334614/how-do-i-install-python-django-modules) And I was reading @Miku answer to the question and I was thinking: Ok, if I just do `pip install --user django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz` (from [Advanced tutorial: How to write reusable apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/reusable-apps/) documentation!) that means that my django proyect should be able to find my app after I add the app to 
`INSTALLED_APPS`?

Because I was following the tutorial and I had the **app folder** right next to `manage.py` file. And know pip says my app is installed and not folder has been created in my project directory.

If this is a really stupid question, please, pardon me, I'm really new to django. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install a python package as a library, it's installed to the python's packages folder, so it can be used from anywhere in the system.

So yes, your Django project should be able to find your app when you add its name in INSTALLED_APPS. If your app doesn't have its own models, you don't even have to include it in the installed apps, and just import from it when you need to use it.

I'm not sure what system you are on, but in Linux, usually installed python packages are located in /usr/lib/{PYTHON VERSION}/site-packages/
(just for a reference)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the answer I was looking for :)