# django project polls stuck at using your own package step

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Python and Django so forgive me if this question seems silly. I'm following the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/reusable-apps/#using-your-own-package) and I'm stuck at the step when you use your own package

The app `mysite` works and there was no error.

I've setup all the required files according to the tutorial.

I've run `python3 setup.py sdist` (inside django-polls folder)

There's the file `django-polls-0.1.tar.gz` in `django-polls/dist/`

```
$ cd ..
$ pip3 install --user django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
Processing ./django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-polls==0.1 from file:///home/viet/webdev/django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz in /home/viet/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Building wheels for collected packages: django-polls
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for django-polls ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/viet/.cache/pip/wheels/ff/ec/8b/85c031efa2ba719d6bd909d20f61ca6b106c79345a1e875f08
Successfully built django-polls
```

Then the tutorial says:

> With luck, your Django project should now work correctly again. Run
>   the server again to confirm this.

How? There's no `manage.py` file in `/django-polls` or in `/home/viet/.cache/pip/wheels/ff/ec/8b/85c031efa2ba719d6bd909d20f61ca6b106c79345a1e875f08`

So I tried this:

```
$ pip3 uninstall django-polls
Uninstalling django-polls-0.1:
  ...
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled django-polls-0.1
$ pip3 install --user django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
Processing ./django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: django-polls
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for django-polls ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/viet/.cache/pip/wheels/ff/ec/8b/85c031efa2ba719d6bd909d20f61ca6b106c79345a1e875f08
Successfully built django-polls
Installing collected packages: django-polls
Successfully installed django-polls-0.1
```

I'm lost at this point.

> Update:

Thank you for your suggestions, I understand now that I need to move the folder `/polls` out of my folder `/mysite` into the folder `/django-polls`

So the tree looks like this:

```
~/webdev$ ls -a
django-polls  mysite
$ cd django-polls/
s$ ls -a
.   dist                   docs     MANIFEST.in  README.rst
..  django_polls.egg-info  LICENSE  polls        setup.py
```

I ran in `/webdev`:

```
$ pip3 install --user django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
Processing ./django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
  ...
Successfully built django-polls

$ cd mysite/

$ python3 manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, polls, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
$ python3 manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 09, 2018 - 09:29:25
Django version 2.0.3, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

I go to localhost:8000/polls:

```
Internal Server Error: /polls/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 158, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 156, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 81, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 63, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 47, in select_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: polls/index.html, polls/question_list.html
[09/Apr/2018 09:29:28] "GET /polls/ HTTP/1.1" 500 83106
```

I just copied the whole `/polls` to `/django-polls` and the built was successful, why I have the error that TemplateDoesNotExist while the `/polls` worked just fine inside `/mysite`?

> Update 2018-04-30

New error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

It ran fine before and I've tried starting the server in a virtual environment but the app doesn't recognise the installed Django.

Comment: You're supposed to run the `manage.py` from `mysite`. The goal is to extract the `polls` app from the project and show that it works if installed from pip, but you still need the Django project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you clarify a little bit more? So I already have the app polls in mysite, if I run manage.py in mysite, it will just show polls, not the django-polls. Is that correct?

Comment: Did Vishal's answer clarify it? To reiterate, the point was to remove `polls` from the project and restore its functionality by installing the package you created.

Comment: I ran through this same tutorial, and was stuck on the same thing for hours until I realized the django-polls package was not installed in the right environment.

Answer (score 2):

Step number 2 in the [packaging your app section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/reusable-apps/#packaging-your-app)  of the tutorial instructs to move polls app out from the project directory to django-polls.

If at this point you run development server, django will throw an exception since polls is listed in installed apps but does not exist in any path visible to python.

When you install the package, pip installs the django-polls package in site-packages directory of your python installation.

At this point, running migrate, should use the polls app from site-packages.

Comment: Thank you. I think your answer is correct. However, I cannot run it. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

1) For the first part of your question: I missunderstood, sorry. @Paulo and @Vishal already explained very well.

2) For the second part: you've installed `django-polls` app successfully, so
your server runs and finds `polls` app, but cannot find **'polls/index.html'** template. That is why you see the error below:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist: polls/index.html, polls/question_list.html
```

You should check wether the template files are in the right place or not.

The templates are located in `path_to_virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\polls\templates\polls` directory if you installed `django-polls` app within a virtual environment. Otherwise (system-wide install), you can look in `python_path\Lib\site-packages\polls\templates\polls`

You might have already solved the problem until now, sorry for answering lately due to some reasons. I hope it helps.

Comment: hi. first of all, thank you for your answer. no, i've been busy with work so i haven't been able to make it work. i've tried to run my old django project again to test your answer and it doesn't work now - somehow??? i'll look at it later when i have free time.

Comment: Could you please tell the newer error you get. As i see you didn't use virtual environment, but i recommend. Within viruatlenv you may try the last tutoial without --user argument.  You may also look for additional sources. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424997/what-does-install-django-app-as-a-user-library-means and https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs

Comment: I've updated my question with the error I have now. It's weird. It ran fine before. I've tried starting the server in a virtual environment but it still doesn't recognise the installed Django.

Comment: When you set up a new virtual environment, you have to install django with `python -m pip install django` inside it. If it's not installed in your virtual env, it won't find django - even if you installed system-wide outside virtual environment. You can look here for a nice explanation: https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/#how-does-a-virtual-environment-work

Answer (score 1):

Here is my case hit the error:

> django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: polls/index.html, polls/question_list.html

I follow this guide: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/reusable-apps/

And, I am using the `virtualenv`.

Here is my folder structure:

```sh
(venv) ☁  mrdulin  tree -L 1 | grep 'django'
├── django-codelab
├── django-polls
```

The error caused by the file name of `MANIFEST.in` file. I copy the file name from guide. But somehow, there is a **empty space** at the beginning of the file name. Which means the file name is

[image]

When I run `python setup.py sdist` command, the output like this:

```sh
(venv) ☁  django-codelab [master] ⚡  ..        
(venv) ☁  mrdulin  cd django-polls        
(venv) ☁  django-polls  python setup.py sdist      
running sdist
running egg_info
creating django_polls.egg-info
writing django_polls.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to django_polls.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to django_polls.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'django_polls.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'django_polls.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'django_polls.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
creating django-polls-0.1
creating django-polls-0.1/django_polls.egg-info
creating django-polls-0.1/polls
creating django-polls-0.1/polls/migrations
copying files to django-polls-0.1...
copying README.rst -> django-polls-0.1
copying setup.cfg -> django-polls-0.1
copying setup.py -> django-polls-0.1
copying django_polls.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> django-polls-0.1/django_polls.egg-info
copying django_polls.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> django-polls-0.1/django_polls.egg-info
copying django_polls.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> django-polls-0.1/django_polls.egg-info
copying django_polls.egg-info/top_level.txt -> django-polls-0.1/django_polls.egg-info
copying polls/__init__.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls
copying polls/admin.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls
copying polls/apps.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls
copying polls/models.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls
copying polls/tests.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls
copying polls/urls.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls
copying polls/views.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls
copying polls/views_old.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls
copying polls/migrations/0001_initial.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls/migrations
copying polls/migrations/__init__.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls/migrations
Writing django-polls-0.1/setup.cfg
creating dist
Creating tar archive
removing 'django-polls-0.1' (and everything under it)
```

**As you can see, the files in `templates`, `static`, `docs` directory are no copied to dist directory. This is the reason.**

After I remove the empty space from file name of `MANIFEST.in` file, run `python setup.py sdist` command again, the output is:

```sh
(venv) ☁  django-polls  python setup.py sdist
running sdist
running egg_info
creating django_polls.egg-info
writing django_polls.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to django_polls.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to django_polls.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'django_polls.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'django_polls.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'django_polls.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
creating django-polls-0.1
creating django-polls-0.1/django_polls.egg-info
creating django-polls-0.1/docs
creating django-polls-0.1/polls
creating django-polls-0.1/polls/migrations
creating django-polls-0.1/polls/static
creating django-polls-0.1/polls/static/polls
creating django-polls-0.1/polls/static/polls/images
creating django-polls-0.1/polls/templates
creating django-polls-0.1/polls/templates/polls
copying files to django-polls-0.1...
copying LICENSE -> django-polls-0.1
copying MANIFEST.in -> django-polls-0.1
copying README.rst -> django-polls-0.1
copying setup.cfg -> django-polls-0.1
copying setup.py -> django-polls-0.1
copying django_polls.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> django-polls-0.1/django_polls.egg-info
copying django_polls.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> django-polls-0.1/django_polls.egg-info
copying django_polls.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> django-polls-0.1/django_polls.egg-info
copying django_polls.egg-info/top_level.txt -> django-polls-0.1/django_polls.egg-info
copying docs/.gitkeep -> django-polls-0.1/docs
copying polls/__init__.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls
copying polls/admin.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls
copying polls/apps.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls
copying polls/models.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls
copying polls/tests.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls
copying polls/urls.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls
copying polls/views.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls
copying polls/views_old.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls
copying polls/migrations/0001_initial.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls/migrations
copying polls/migrations/__init__.py -> django-polls-0.1/polls/migrations
copying polls/static/polls/style.css -> django-polls-0.1/polls/static/polls
copying polls/static/polls/images/background.jpg -> django-polls-0.1/polls/static/polls/images
copying polls/templates/polls/detail.html -> django-polls-0.1/polls/templates/polls
copying polls/templates/polls/index.html -> django-polls-0.1/polls/templates/polls
copying polls/templates/polls/results.html -> django-polls-0.1/polls/templates/polls
Writing django-polls-0.1/setup.cfg
creating dist
Creating tar archive
removing 'django-polls-0.1' (and everything under it)
(venv) ☁  django-polls
```

Now, the files in `template`, `static`, `docs` directory are copied to dist directory.

Then, change directory to `django-codelab`, run below command:

```sh
pip3 install ../django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
```

Add `polls` application into `INSTALLED_APPS` list:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls',
    # 'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Run the server:

```sh
python manage.py runserver
```

It works perfectly! **So, the tutorial is correct. Please check your steps and be careful with coding**

Answer (score 1):

You should verify that the

> django-polls

was successfully installed base on the command you fired up

```
pip install --user django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
```

I'm on windows and it will install inside if successfull

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages
-->django_polls-0.1-py3.7.egg-info
-->polls
```

if you only see

```
-->django_polls-0.1-py3.7.egg-info
```

then you should double check your `setup.cfg` if you write it correctly including the indents then run `python setup.py sdist` again

if all are correct then run the server just like before (`manage.py`) inside the project where you pulled out `polls` directory (the same project you used before)

```
D:\websiteprojects\djangotutorial01\mysite>python manage.py runserver
```

(remember) `polls` folder is no longer inside that

```
D:\websiteprojects\djangotutorial01\mysite>
```

but it still will run because it was successfully installed inside

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages
```