# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djangofeeds'

Tags: django, celery

I have followed the sample code given in the [task-cookbook](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time) Ensuring a task is only executed one at a time

That code uses

```
from djangofeeds.models import Feed
```

I do not know where to get the djangofeeds module from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Python/Django Modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334614/how-do-i-install-python-django-modules)

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you want a package, you'd search https://pypi.org/ for it and follow the instructions you find.

In this instance there is a module here; https://github.com/operasoftware/django-feeds

This appears to be the same package. However it doesn't appear to be released to pypi.

So you could download it & add it to your project or install the package from the downloaded archive, instructions for that here; https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-local-archives

Answer (score 0):

djangofeeds' actual package name is `django-feeds`, not `djangofeeds`.

Thereby you can install that package with `pip install django-feeds`.

Answer (score 0):

Just install djangofeed, `pip install django-feeds/djangofeeds` or `pip3 install django-feeds//djangofeeds` if you're using `python3`.